# When do you use ganache-cli and when do you use ganache-core?

Tags: web3js, ganache, web3-providers

I have seen two usages over the internet

1.

```
const ganache = require("ganache-cli");
web3.setProvider(ganache.provider());
```

2.

```
const ganache = require("ganache-core");
web3.setProvider(ganache.provider());
```

What is the main differene in these two cases. I know that `ganache-cli` utilizes `ganache-core`. What is the addon that `ganache-cli` is providing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ganache [github](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli) clearly mentions below statement.

> ganache-cli utilizes ganache-core internally, which is distributed
>   with optional native dependencies for increased performance. If these
>   native dependencies fail to install on your system ganache-cli will
>   automatically fallback to ganache-core’s pre-bundled JavaScript build.

You can use ganache-core as well but depending on your system you may get better performance using ganache-cli .